# How do I fetch data from oracle table for interval 5 hour

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

This question is for database oracle, I have table A which have data for one week for every hour like below

```
----------------------------
NAME   | CODE | INSERTDATE (Timestamp- datatype)
----------------------------
YYY    | Y    | 11/8/2017 1:32:22.000000000 PM
zzz    | Z    | 11/8/2017 2:32:22.000000000 PM
aaa    | A    | 11/8/2017 3:32:22.000000000 PM
bbb    | B    | 11/8/2017 4:32:22.000000000 PM
ccc    | C    | 11/8/2017 5:32:22.000000000 PM
SSS    | S    | 11/8/2017 6:32:22.000000000 PM
...    | .    | ..............................
...    | .    | ..............................
...    | .    | ..............................
RRR    | R    | 11/8/2017 11:32:22.000000000 PM
```

table have data for duration of one week and I am looking to select every record after 5 hour. (so total records are 168 and I need output 168/5= 33 or 34 records) like below

For Ex
table A

```
----------------------------
NAME   | CODE | INSERTDATE (Timestamp- datatype)
----------------------------
YYY    | Y    | 11/8/2017 1:32:22.000000000 PM
SSS    | S    | 11/8/2017 6:32:22.000000000 PM
RRR    | R    | 11/8/2017 11:32:22.000000000 PM
...    | .    | ..............................
...    | .    | ..............................
...    | .    | ..............................
```

Please suggest how can I get this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what output you are expecting. Adding an "expected result" would really help.

Answer (score 0):

For the datatype `timestamp` the syntax of adding time is `+ INTERVAL '5' HOUR` or just use the minus symbol to subtract. It may be used anywhere you need such a calculation as the following example shows:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/366dc/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (NAME varchar2(3), CODE varchar2(1), INSERTDATE timestamp)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("NAME", "CODE", "INSERTDATE")
         VALUES ('YYY', 'Y', '08-Nov-2017 01:32:22 PM')
    INTO Table1 ("NAME", "CODE", "INSERTDATE")
         VALUES ('SSS', 'S', '08-Nov-2017 06:32:22 PM')
    INTO Table1 ("NAME", "CODE", "INSERTDATE")
         VALUES ('RRR', 'R', '08-Nov-2017 11:32:22 PM')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
   *
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.INSERTDATE = (t2.INSERTDATE + interval '5' HOUR)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/366dc/3/0)**:

```
| NAME | CODE |         t1.INSERTDATE |   NAME |   CODE |         t2.INSERTDATE |
|------|------|-----------------------|--------|--------|-----------------------|
|  SSS |    S | 2017-11-08 18:32:22.0 |    YYY |      Y | 2017-11-08 13:32:22.0 |
|  RRR |    R | 2017-11-08 23:32:22.0 |    SSS |      S | 2017-11-08 18:32:22.0 |
|  YYY |    Y | 2017-11-08 13:32:22.0 | (null) | (null) |                (null) |
```

Comment: I have data of one week for every hour, I pinged that data just as an example to show what I am looking for, and above query is not giving correct result

Comment: OK. Howver you have not **shown** "*what I am looking for*" so no-one can match that expectation. **Edit your question** to show the wanted result of that data

Comment: Is your question solved now? Do you still have questions about this answer?